# Trying to find childhood recipe: Chocolate pudding covered in graham cracker dust

Tags: dessert, pudding, mousse, graham-crackers

I'm trying to find a childhood recipe.

**Best I can remember it's this**:
Chocolate pudding/mousse covered in graham cracker dust.

It doesn't really have a shape. It's like a blob. When you look at it all you see is graham cracker crust. When you scoop some with your spoon you see the mousse/pudding.

Anybody ever seen / heard of this? Or could it really be as simple as making some pudding and covering it in graham cracker crust?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes.  (it could really be as simple as making some pudding and covering it in crushed graham cracker).

Comment: And on the 'has anyone seen this' front, my mom used to make something that was called a 'dirt cake' that was chocolate mousse covered in cookie crumbs ... but it also had gummy worms in it, and was served in a flower pot with fake flowers.

Comment: I know this "dirt cake" as "molehill cake" less worms, more moles ;) and able to serve at a cake plate